# Managing letters of recommendation

Tags: recommendation-letter

I write many letters of recommendation for students applying to graduate school, fellowships, or faculty positions.

Some universities have a letter service, where the letter writer can upload a letter to the service and the service takes care of uploading the letter to each individual school/fellowship/etc. that the student chooses to apply to.  However, my university does not.

How can I make this process as efficient as possible?  Or, are there external companies that provide this service?

(I realize that most universities and fellowships have moved to online submission of letters.  However, it still takes some time to upload my letter to each university and fellowship's individual system, so it would save time if there is a service to help with that.)